# What is the easiest way that you can fathom to draw solid black across an OpenGL display temporarily for a 'panic button'?

Tags: opengl, 3d

As in the title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [glClear](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glClear.html).

```
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
SwapBuffers();
```